# Where can I find the source for Iframe Id# FilteredItemsList_frame_details?

Tags: cme

Version: SDL Tridion 2011 SP1
I'm trying to find out where I can make changes to the style **tr.selected td {
background: #DFEAF7!important;
color: #000;
}**  But it seems it lives in a style located in Iframe Id# FilteredItemsList_frame_details?

[image: Dashboard]

Comment: Have a look at Tridion's GUI Extension Framework: http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_DC9C231E60874E3386BBAF129328D9AD (login required).  This would be the entry point to customize the Tridion GUI.

Comment: That should be an answer nick

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest adding a new GUI Extension and then in the extension using javascript to change the class or behavior of the item and override the default Tridion style.  As an example, please see my post on changing the width of the Tridion tree iFrame window.  http://www.curlette.com/?p=901